# Cannot load Tensorflow model in java using SavedModelBundle

Tags: java, maven, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to load mobilenet model from this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#pre-trained-models). The model is stored on disk at the following path

`C:\Users\userName\IdeaProjects\ImageClassification\src\main\resources\mobilenet_v2_1.4_224\mobilenet_v2_1.4_224.pb`

Following is the code which is located at this path `C:\Users\userName\IdeaProjects\ImageClassification\src\main\java\com\DeepLearning\ImgClassification.java`

```
try(SavedModelBundle modelBundle = SavedModelBundle.load("src/main/resources/mobilenet_v2_1.4_224", "serve")){
            Session mobileNetSession = modelBundle.session();

            System.out.println(mobileNetSession);

        }catch (TensorFlowException t){
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());
        }
```

I am trying to load the .pb using `SavedModelBundle.load()`, but I get the following error

```
2020-07-31 12:40:35.385591: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: src/main/resources/mobilenet_v2_1.4_224
2020-07-31 12:40:35.570627: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2020-07-31 12:40:35.577560: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:311] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: fail. Took 191903 microseconds.
Could not find meta graph def matching supplied tags: { serve }. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: `saved_model_cli`
```

How do I resolve the path of the model?
What am I mising here?
Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using SavedModelBundle(), I loaded the model using ReadBinaryProto() in C++. tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def;// Graph definition for the current model

  Status load_graph_status =
      ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), graph_file_name, &graph_def);// read graph from pb_file
  if (!load_graph_status.ok()) {
    return tensorflow::errors::NotFound("Failed to load compute graph at '",
                                        graph_file_name, "'");
  }